# Add conditional CSS class to "add to cart" button on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

What I want to do is depending on a conditional, add a class to the add to cart button on the WooCommerce single product page.

Example:

The actual class of the add cart button

```html
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="10661" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Pre - Ordenar</button>
```

What I want to achieve if the condition is true:

```html
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="10661" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt preordenar">Pre - Ordenar</button>
```

This would be an example code.

```php
function addclasses( $classes )
{      
    global $product;
    //we apply condition if it returns true applies the class in the cart.
    if ( self::product_can_be_pre_ordered( $product ) ) {
        $classes[]='preordenar';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

So far the function but I don't know what hook to use to add it to WooCommerce, on the single product page.

**NOTE:** The function is not quite correct and optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** `product_can_be_pre_ordered( $product )` is not available in WooCommerce by default, so I replaced it with `$product->is_featured()` in my answer. **Adapt to your needs**.

---

Since the add to cart button on the single product page is **based on template files, you actually need to overwrite them** to answer your question

In the */templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php* template file - (This template can be overridden by copying it to *yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php.*)

Replace

```php
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
```

With

```php
<?php
if ( $product->is_featured() ) {
    $extra_class = ' my-featured-class';
} else {
    $extra_class = '';
}
?>

<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt <?php echo $extra_class; ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
```

---

**Because overwriting template files is possible, but it is preferably not recommended, you can always use a workaround**. For example by adding a **class on a parent div**:

```php
/**
 * WooCommerce Post Class filter.
 *
 * @since 3.6.2
 * @param array      $classes Array of CSS classes.
 * @param WC_Product $product Product object.
 */
function filter_woocommerce_post_class( $classes, $product ) {
    // is_product() - Returns true on a single product page, NOT the single product page, so return
    if ( ! is_product() ) return $classes;

    // Returns whether or not the product is featured
    if ( $product->is_featured() ) {
        // Add new class
        $classes[] = 'my-featured-class';
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'filter_woocommerce_post_class', 10, 2 );
```

**Note:** the class/classes will also be applied to the related products, generated by a "loop" on the single product page.

To prevent this, use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_post_class( $classes, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    
    // is_product() - Returns true on a single product page, NOT the single product page, so return
    if ( ! is_product() ) return $classes;
    
    // The related products section, so return
    if ( $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ) return $classes;

    // Returns whether or not the product is featured
    if ( $product->is_featured() ) {
        // Add new class
        $classes[] = 'my-featured-class';
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'filter_woocommerce_post_class', 10, 2 );
```

---

Then you can apply the CSS as follows:

```css
.my-featured-class .single_add_to_cart_button {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

---

**Related:** [How to add classes to WooCommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64805994/11987538)